# Attempting to call a FullCalendar method on an element with no calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Receiving a warning for "Attempting to call a FullCalendar method on an element with no calendar."

It happens when calling `$('#calendar_' + calendarId).fullCalendar('clientEvents');`

I do have multiple "FullCalendar" implementations on the same page.  Would this effect anything?

### EDIT

Here is how I am creating the FullCalendar.  The above line is just referencing the events from the calendar with nothing special going on.

```
$('#calendar_' + id).fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#calendar_' + id).fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        $('#calendar_' + id).fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        var newUrl = calEvent.url.replace("%26", "&");

        window.location = newUrl;

        return false;
    },
    header: {
        left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var view = $('#calendar_' + id).fullCalendar('getView');

        if (view.name == 'agendaDay') {
            window.location.replace('/Create?start=' + start._d.toJSON() + '&end=' + end._d.toJSON() + '&isUTC=true&redirectToCalendar=true');
        }
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    timezone: 'local',
    viewRender: getEvents
});
```

### EDIT 2

See the screen capture to show it working on this line that I have already discussed.  I have 3 calendars on the page.  The first works as expected with no warning.  The second and third show a warning, but the events are retrieved.

[image]

Comment: No it wouldn't but if `'#calendar_' + calendarId` doesn't match an element on your page which has currently got a fullCalendar attached to it, then you'd get that message. Check the value of `calendarId` when you run this code, and check it makes it into a valid ID where you've previously attached a calendar, and check you haven't destroyed the calendar on that element. Unfortunately, you haven't provided us enough code to debug any of that on your behalf.

Comment: thanks for the update but it doesn't allow us to reproduce your issue. Like I said, you need to debug the line `('#calendar_' + calendarId).fullCalendar('clientEvents');` and check that `calendarId` is actually correct etc.

Comment: @ADyson - it is correct.  it returns all of the events from the calendar.

Comment: If that works and returns all your events then clearly it's not the source of the error...

Comment: @ADyson - I added a screen capture to show you what's going on.